# When I add the namespace my code inside class is not get executed

Tags: php

I am working on crud operation.my code is working fine ,but when I add the namespace its not working.then I have debug the code to find where is problem.
    I took one file  where database connection code is written inside constructor, file is DbConfig.php.
      In that file add the namespace and create the object of class inside DbConfig.php.and tried to run that file 
      "$this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=crudOperation",'root', 'root');" after this line it dont work(i check it with echo "Hi")

```
<?php
namespace Foo;
class DbConfig 
{
    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $username = 'root';
    private $password = 'root';
    private $database = 'crudOperation';
    public $connection;


    public function __construct()
    { 
      if (!isset($this->connection)) {

            try{
                 echo "Hi";
                $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=crudOperation",'root', 'root');
                echo "Hi";
                $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                 echo "Hi";
                return $this->connection;
                } catch(PDOException $e) {
                die("Failed to connect with MySQL: " . $e->getMessage());
                }


        } else{
            echo "Connection failed";
        }

    }
}
$abc= new DbConfig();
```

Comment: use `new \PDO...` and also for the other classes that are out of the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces in PHP are relative. So if you are inside one namespace, anything that's outside that namespace requires an absolute reference.

```
class Global {}

namespace A { class Foo {} }

namespace B { class Bar {} }

namespace B\C { class Baz {} }

namespace B
{
  \Global::doIt(); //Absolute

  \A\Foo::doIt(); //Absolute

  Bar::doIt(); //Relative
  \B\Bar::doIt(); //Absolute

  C\Baz::doIt(); //Relative
  \B\C\Baz::doIt(); //Absolute
}
```